# Modify message displayed on post save

Tags: filters, hooks

After a post is updated there is a message displayed, how can I change the displayed text? I would like to remove the "view post" link and change the 'Post published' text. I'd like to do this for a particular post type.
Here is the html WordPress outputs:

```
<div id="message" class="updated below-h2"><p>Post published. <a href="http://localhost/wp/wp30/feeds/449/">View post</a></p></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'feed_updated_messages' );
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type